# How to code for Link button click event opens modal popup in mvc3.0 with Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have webgrid as follows

```
@grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column(
    "FirstName",format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink((string)item.FirstName, "Details", "product", new { id = item.FirstName }, null)</text>),
    grid.Column("LastName","Last")
))
```

if i click the Firstname link the modal popup should open? How to do this in mvc3.0?

Answer (score 1):

Recommend http://fancybox.net.

Add document.ready for fancybox. (look at examples and documentation)

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox({
            'autoScale': false,
            'autoDimensions': true,
            'transitionIn': 'none',
            'transitionOut': 'none',
            'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
            'hideOnContentClick': true,
            'showCloseButton': true,
            'type': 'ajax'
        });
    });
```

Then you change your actionlink to have a class that fancybox can attach to.

```
@Html.ActionLink((string)item.FirstName, "Details", "product"
    , new { id = item.FirstName }, new {Class = "fancybox"})
```